# How to embedded twitter widget into android phonegap

Tags: android, html, twitter, cordova

I have tried to embed a twitter widget to my android apps, but the timeline does not show. Just a blank page when I run it on my android devices. Is there any configuration I need to make. FYI, I am using jquerymobile and phonegap to make my android apps.

Thank you.

Edit :

This is my code. I copied it on the official twitter website. I paste this code inside the body tag as i using HTML5 to make my android apps.

!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

Comment: Please post your code and also which twitter widget you used.

Comment: @RyanWeir this is my code. I use twitter widget on official twitter website. I paste this code on inside the body tag. FYI I'm using HTML5 to make the apps

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things you may need to do.

I was having issues with the Twitter Embedded Timeline as well in PhoneGap Build when on android and iOS.

in my config.xml I whitelisted a few different domains.

```
<access origin="https://twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://platform.twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://platform.twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com" />
<access origin="http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com" />
```

you may be wondering where I came up with the last ones.  When I was running it through Chrome Developer Tools I happened to spot that as a domain that was being accessed via the Twitter-provided Script.  This may be different for you depending on location, but at least it's a starting point.  And I am well aware that I probably don't need to duplicate for secure and un-secure http, but better safe than sorry.

****EDIT****

I created a new HTML document called twitterfeed.html.   Then I called an onClick event to a method that accessed the new html page in the InAppBrowser.  This should help you, however I am still working on the Twitter Intents.

```
  function twittertest(){
 var ref = window.open('twitterfeed.html', '_blank', 'location=no');    
};
```

calling the function:

```
 <img id="twt_image" class="small_image"  src="assets/images/tw_image.png" alt="mctn_twitter" onClick="twittertest()"></img>
```

I have mine opening from an image but you could just as easily add that onClick to something else.

Comment: I have list all the domain at my config.xml but still on my android devices the timeline is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline) service and detailed description.
It uses InAppBrowser plugin and works for both iOS and Android apps